# Design patterns for junior java developer

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, java

Как вы считаете, какие из паттернов проектирования необходимо знать в первую очередь Junior Java-деву для успешного прохождения собеседований? Поделитесь опытом прохождения собеседований..

Comment: открыли бы книжку, просмотрели, ознакомились. Их там не так много.

Comment: Java-дэв? Страшное создание. Мне понравилось.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте книгу "Head First Design Patterns" (есть русский перевод). Там очень понятно объясняются паттерны. Не все, но для джуниора достаточно. После этого можно будет почитать GOF и узнать о паттернах побольше. Также, если будете работать веб-разработчиком, стоит узнать о паттернах J2EE. Но это уже не на джуниора.